# Responsive three column div layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am developing a footer in a three column layout. I need this footer to be responsive that each div is stacked under each other on mobile devices excluding tablets.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="footer-pages">

<div class="footer-container">  
    <div id="one">
        container1
    </div>

    <div id="two">
        container2
    </div>

    <div id="three">
        container3
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#footer-pages{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
background-color:red;    
}

.footer-container{
   width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
   }

#one, #two, #three{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    }
```

Here is also a fiddle of where I managed to achieve yet: http://jsfiddle.net/5L2RY/

Can someone guide me how to achieve this ?

Comment: "I need this footer to be responsive that each div is stacked under each other." When do you need it to stack..? please update the question with proper info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this at end of css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #one, #two, #three{
        width:auto;
        float:none;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2RY/1/embedded/result/)

[About Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

use @media query.
visit this site

[Media Query Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min-width` or `@media queries` as other answers are explaining.

```
#one, #two, #three{
    ...
    min-width:100px; 
}
```

Updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2RY/2/)**.